# Is `echo $TEST` expanding an asterisk in the variable a bug?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution, variable-substitution

Is this a Bash bug?

```
$ mkdir test && cd test && echo "a" > "some.file"
test$ echo '*'
*
test$ TEST=$(echo '*')
test$ echo $TEST
some.file
```

Why is the second output the resolution of `*` into (all) filenames instead of just a literal `*` output? Looks like a bug in Bash?

Tried on Ubuntu 18.04, bash version 4.4.19(1)-release. Expect it will be the same on other OS'es.

Comment: General procedure when finding bugs in Unix: 1) Check out Single Unix Specification online for relevant definitions and rationales. 2) Submit a bugreport to austingroupbugs.net 3) Submit bugreport to the developer (with a patch if possible).

Comment: @DannyNiu: Your comment is not very practical.  Documents like POSIX and the Single Unix Specification do not consist of millions and millions of examples; they contain explanations (with, maybe, a few examples).  Those documents are of little help to somebody who doesn’t understand what is happening and why; reading them is like learning to drive by reading a roadmap. And this question isn’t asking what to do.  If you want to post a question, “What should I do if I’ve found a bug in a widely used software product?”, and post an answer, go ahead.

Comment: @G-Man I did find DannyNiu's answer helpful in terms of the information provided, "just in case".

Comment: Try the `set -f` (and `set +f`) options before/after the final `echo` to disable globbing/wildcard expansion if this behavior is unwanted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. You have shown that

```
echo '*'
```

will produce a literal `*`. Hence when you substitute this output, as per the following command

```
TEST=$(echo '*')
```

it will put `*` into the variable `$TEST`. Then when you

```
echo $TEST
```

the glob will expand here. You can verify this by running this last command, changing directories, then running it again.

You will get the `*` output if you say

```
echo "$TEST"
```

as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/80216#131767),
the double quotes allow the variable to be expanded
but prevent the glob from expanding.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thank you. I missed the fact that the echo * does not have quotes and thus resolves. It's harder to see when you have it inside a complex script :) Makes sense now.

Comment: @Roel FWIW, after a few years of experience you will start to treat `$TEST` instead of `"$TEST"` as a code smell and it becomes a bit easier to see. It's still not much of a smell though so it will still trip you up sometimes

Comment: And this is why my general approach is, if it starts with a dollar, quote it :). Yes, you CAN learn the specific cases where you don't have to - but it's almost always harmless to quote them in cases where you don't have to, so you may as well just quote your variables everywhere!

Comment: @slebetman: And for the rest of us without this instinct, `shellcheck` will do the complaining (  https://www.shellcheck.net/ ).

Comment: @Roel many decades ago, I learned -- the hard way -- that 99.99999% of the time it's your fault, not a bug in the compiler or interpreter... :)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure either :) Otherwise I would have attempted a bug report :)